# How to type an object with generic keys of different types in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How would you type this objects in typescript ?

I have one special "datetime" key that is a Date, the rest of the keys are numbers. But I don't know in advance which keys will be set on each object. Examples values:

```
type Metrics = ??????

const example1: Metrics = {
  datetime: new Date(),
  activity: 12.34,
  min: 12.34,
  max: 12.34,
}
const example2: Metrics = {
  datetime: new Date(),
  avg: 12.34,
}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
type Metrics = {
  datetime: Date,
  [key: string]: number,
}
// ERROR on the type definition:
// Property 'datetime' of type 'Date' is not assignable to string index type 'number'


type Metrics = { 
    datetime: Date 
} & {  
    [key: string]: number 
}
// ERROR on the variable assignment:
// Type '{ datetime: Date; activity: number; min: number; max: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Metrics'.
//   Type '{ datetime: Date; activity: number; min: number; max: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: number | null; }'.
//     Property 'datetime' is incompatible with index signature.
//       Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: Do you have control over the format of this data? Because your life will be a lot easier if you nest that numerical data in its own object where _all_ keys are numbers. `{ datetime: Date, data: { [key: string]: number }`

Comment: If you define key for all properties then "datetime" also needs to fullfit it:
`{ [key: string]: number | Date, datetime: Date }`

Comment: @AlexWayne In fact I do, and that's what is currently implemented, but I would enjoy a solution to this to simplify my data format.

Comment: @fard yeah, that's what I observed. But my metric keys cannot be a Date, this type is now wrong for metrics keys. Also, I cannot specify properties keys in advance as there are pulled from the database

Comment: @ClémentPrévost if you can specify all properties: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAslEAnAlgYwNJTAZxgXhgCIBDNEFANxXCJgB9iBbFAOzsaKZIA8PiSlAOZFgoSLATJ0eQgG9gMJTAAmJEIhRMoALhgARdVGABfGADIYABRJIKJADYAeAEpQ0AeyQqnU1JmwcABoYVgBXJgAjKCQAPlixT1YcEBgoHhImCAcoAEY9PxkCGAUlNQ0KbT1WKAB3AyMACgBKIMUYMgpqcD1cgCYAOgBmABY2pRZWXsHR8ZhuHmnhsdNgJJS0jKycvoLEf1kS9vLNKtC6ho0WucEhJdnTIA

Comment: @ClémentPrévost then don't change it. Typescript doesn't really support this "indexed type with exceptions" case. All properties of an object _must_ be compatible with its index signature. The proper way to handle this is usually to separate the interface with known keys from the interfaces with unknown keys so you are always working with either one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want something that uses `Record<Exclude<K,"datetime">, number>` to map all present keys to type number but exclude the key "datetime". Since this won't necessarily be possible with a usual index type you are probably best off using a helper function that constrains the type as a generic:

```
type Metrics<K extends keyof any> = { datetime: Date } & Record<Exclude<K, "datetime">, number>;

function makeMetrics<T extends Metrics<keyof T>>(metrics: T): T {
    return metrics;
}

const example1 = makeMetrics({
    datetime: new Date(),
    activity: 12.34,
    min: 12.34,
    max: 12.34,
});
const example2 = makeMetrics({
    datetime: new Date(),
    avg: 12.34,
});
```

This means that both examples will only allow the keys that are present when it is defined, adding extra keys later would not, in order to allow that you'd need something like "all keys except `datetime` are numbers" which is not possible as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky but I found a way to do this to add a type based on your object. This allows you to export a typed object.

1. Define your object without a type

```
const example1 = {
  datetime: new Date(),
  activity: 12.34,
  min: 12.34,
  max: 12.34,
}
```

2. Create a type from that object but exclude the specific keys you want to change

```
type AllKeys<T> = {
  [Property in keyof T]: number;
};
```

3. Create an intersection type using the type from 2 and omit your datetime key. Note that "typeof example1" gives you all of the keys from example1.

```
type NewType = AllKeys<Omit<typeof example1, "datetime">> & { datetime: Date};
```

4. export the typed object

```
export const example: NewType = example1;
```