# Typescript - Key/value type with known keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an object which look like this:

```js
const o: A = {
    id: 'foo',
    key1: 123,
    key2: 456
}
```

`id` is a known and required property of type `string`. Other keys are dynamic and are numbers.

How to define this in typescript?

I already tried this:

```js
type A = {
    id: string;
    [key: string]: number
} // Doesn't work
```

or this

```
type A = {
    id: string 
} & {
    [key: string]: number
} // Doesn't work either
```

TS won't accept the string on ID and expect it to be a number

Any solution ?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64160111/how-to-type-an-object-with-generic-keys-of-different-types-in-typescript.

Answer (score 2):

```js
type MyObject<K extends keyof any> = { id: string } & Record<Exclude<K, "id">, number>;

function myObjectWrapper<T extends MyObject<keyof T>>(metrics: T): MyObject<keyof T> {
    return metrics;
}

const a = myObjectWrapper({
    id: "foo",
    key1: 123,
    key2: 456
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you defined `[key: string]: number` and type parameter is main. So each key identifier must has number type (and ID is used for intellisense). To solve it, you must do this:

```js
type A = {
    id: string;
    [key: string]: number | string
};
var a: A = {
    id: "foo",
    key1: 123,
    key2: "bar" // this is also valid
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I _don't_ want other keys to be string, I just want number. This could make the error go away but my type would be less strict

Comment: I know, that's the problem of actual TypeScript. If you say [key: string]: number, it must be number in all cases. Another solution doesn't exists