# Typescript: Typings with ForOf Values beign unknown

Tags: typescript

I started by taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172356/typescript-key-value-type-with-known-keys). But this was using their own typing. I am doing a forof object.entries. I have a set of values like below, I have found that I have to check the instance of to access functions on that type of object. Which make sense for all but string. I have to use `String` for `instanceof` string but then I get errors because `String` isn't assignable to `string`. So I am lost on what to do, or if there is a better way to do this.

```js
    const value = 
    {
        EnableDataMining: 1, EnableReassembly: 0, Alarm: [1,2,3],
        AllowQuery: 1, AllowDrilldown: 1, MessageType: ["sms", "msm","carrier pidgeon"],
        AllowBypass: 0, Bybass: (1) [false, "01/01/1970"]
    }

    for(const [k, v] of Object.entries(value))
    {
        th.headers = td.headers = th.textContent = key;
                    
        if(v instanceof Array) v.map(i => td.textContent = i);
        if(v instanceof Number) td.textContent = v.toString();
        if(v instanceof String) td.textContent = v;

        console.log(k, v);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to check if `v` is a string (or a number) is to use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
if (typeof v === "number") td.textContent = v.toString();
if (typeof v === "string") td.textContent = v;
```

Note that `"string"` and `"number"` are in quotes. `typeof v` gives you a string that you need to check.

Comment: Ah I see, I was trying to do it based of the instance. Thank you!